# rewrite friendly url with .htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to make Friendly URLs, but when I try my PHP code works correctly but my CSS and JS files are not loaded correctly. It tries to get these files from different path.
I'm using WAMP, and I've created bsp directory for my project.
There are two folders for js and css files and I've used the css and js files in my php pages like

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu_config.js">< / script >
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" / >
```

and the `.htaccess` file code is here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).html$   products.php?maid=$1-$2 [L]
```

But when I browse through url `http://localhost/bsp/products/2_7.html`,

It does not load the js and css files.. at that time the path of `js` and `css` files becomes
`http://localhost/bsp/products/css/menu.css` etc
the `css` and `js` path should be `http://localhost/bsp/css/menu.css`.

I hope anybody will understand this problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to do with your paths when including the files. You're currently using relative links, which means that "js/menu_config.js" will be appended onto the current URL.

Instead, you need an absolute path. By prepending your URLs with a /, you denote that you want to specify the path relative to the document root (rather than the current subdirectory). I'll leave out what the paths should be for now, filling them in is an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="/js/menu_config.js">< / script >
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css" / >
```